# beautiful soup scraping table with filter (show number of rows) export to csv

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Dave here I am trying to scrape a daily price index from a https://www.ctmarket.co.za/daily-prices/. I am a complete newbie but I have managed to get the Data from the table into the console using this code. My issue above the table there is a filter to select how many rows you would like to show at the moment I can only get the default 10rows. the plan is to help local farmers track pricing in the markets so I need to pull this data daily and plot an analysis

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen(
    'https://www.ctmarket.co.za/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_wdtable&table_id=1').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    
print(row)
```

Comment: there's a post param `length` with the number of rows desired specified. default is 10. puppeteer might be better for pre-scrape interaction.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get("https://www.ctmarket.co.za/daily-prices/")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        columns = [x.text for x in soup.select('th.wdtheader')]
        data = {
            "draw": "1",
            "columns[0][data]": "0",
            "columns[0][name]": "id",
            "columns[0][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[0][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[0][search][value]": "",
            "columns[0][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[1][data]": "1",
            "columns[1][name]": "item",
            "columns[1][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[1][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[1][search][value]": "",
            "columns[1][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[2][data]": "2",
            "columns[2][name]": "description",
            "columns[2][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[2][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[2][search][value]": "",
            "columns[2][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[3][data]": "3",
            "columns[3][name]": "grade",
            "columns[3][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[3][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[3][search][value]": "",
            "columns[3][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[4][data]": "4",
            "columns[4][name]": "container",
            "columns[4][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[4][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[4][search][value]": "",
            "columns[4][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[5][data]": "5",
            "columns[5][name]": "container_count",
            "columns[5][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[5][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[5][search][value]": "",
            "columns[5][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[6][data]": "6",
            "columns[6][name]": "mass",
            "columns[6][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[6][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[6][search][value]": "",
            "columns[6][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[7][data]": "7",
            "columns[7][name]": "low_price",
            "columns[7][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[7][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[7][search][value]": "",
            "columns[7][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[8][data]": "8",
            "columns[8][name]": "high_price",
            "columns[8][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[8][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[8][search][value]": "",
            "columns[8][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[9][data]": "9",
            "columns[9][name]": "avg_price",
            "columns[9][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[9][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[9][search][value]": "",
            "columns[9][search][regex]": "false",
            "columns[10][data]": "10",
            "columns[10][name]": "date_updated",
            "columns[10][searchable]": "true",
            "columns[10][orderable]": "true",
            "columns[10][search][value]": "",
            "columns[10][search][regex]": "false",
            "order[0][column]": "0",
            "order[0][dir]": "asc",
            "start": "0",
            "length": "1000",
            "search[value]": "",
            "search[regex]": "false",
            "wdtNonce": "3af0c4e83d"
        }
        params = {
            'action': 'get_wdtable',
            'table_id': 1
        }
        r = req.post(url, params=params, data=data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data'], columns=columns).iloc[:, 1:]
        print(df)


main('https://www.ctmarket.co.za/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php')
```

Output:

```
     item         description grade  ... high_price avg_price         date_updated
0    APBR      APPLE BRAEBURN    1X  ...     140.00    140.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
1    APCP   APPLE CRIPPS PINK    1M  ...     100.00    100.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
2    APCP   APPLE CRIPPS PINK    1M  ...     150.00    150.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
3    APCR    APPLE CRIPPS RED    1M  ...     140.00    140.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
4    APFU          APPLE FUJI    2M  ...      40.00     40.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
..    ...                 ...   ...  ...        ...       ...                  ...
462  TORO   TOMATOES ROMANITA    1Z  ...      35.00      0.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
463  TOSE  TOMATOES SALADETTE    1R  ...      45.00     45.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
464  TURN             Turnips        ...       5.00      5.00  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
465  TURN             Turnips        ...      60.00     44.72  04/08/2021 11:19 AM
466  WOOD            Firewood        ...      50.00     48.33  04/08/2021 11:19 AM

[467 rows x 10 columns]
```

Comment: @DavidMorris https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers